# Refinishing old cement basement floor: Is cement skim coat an option?

Tags: basement, floor, cement

our basement floor is very old and in poor condition. What are good options to refinish the floor? Is it possible to skim coat with cement and then paint or is the condition of the current floor not sufficient? Are there good alternatives?

Context: Before refinishing the floor, we will install a french drain around the perimeter of the basement that hopefully addresses the water issue visible in the pictures. The goal is not to have a perfect floor. It doesn't have to be level etc.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd consider an epoxy finish.  A cement skim coat will just flake off.